# Align equals inside case statement

Tags: align, cases

I have the following code:

```
\begin{equation}
\frac {\partial C}{\partial {z_k}}= \begin{cases}
  - \frac {1} {y_i} {y_i} (1-{y_i}) = y_{i} - 1 & k = i \\
   \frac {1} {y_i} {y_{i}^{2}} = y_{i}  &  k \ne i  \\
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
```

It works fine, but what I want to achieve is to align the `=` from the first case and the second case. I did not manage to do that.

Any advice?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can be done, using `aligned` instead, but I am not sure which exact alignment is desirable.  Probably the best is to use a second cases for the simplification.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \frac {\partial C}{\partial {z_k}}
  =
  \left\{
  \begin{aligned}
    - \frac {1} {y_i} {y_i} (1-{y_i})&= y_{i} - 1, &\qquad& k = i, \\
    \frac {1} {y_i} {y_{i}^{2}}&= y_{i},  &&  k \ne i.
  \end{aligned}
  \right.
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
    \frac {\partial C}{\partial {z_k}} &=
    \begin{dcases}
      - \frac {1} {y_i} {y_i} (1-{y_i}),& k = i, \\
      \frac {1} {y_i} {y_{i}^{2}}, & k \ne i,
    \end{dcases}\\
    &=
    \begin{cases}
      y_{i} - 1, &k = i, \\
      y_{i}, & k \ne i.
    \end{cases}
  \end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining and for giving me multiple options. I tried both (I was inclined to use the first one due in order to not take so much space) but I agree that the second one looks better, so I used that one.

Answer (score 0):

It will suffice to insert 
    \hspace{3.9em} 
at the beginning of your fourth line (the exact amount  of space depends on 
the fontsize and the font you have chosen.

Comment: Such manual adjustment is generally not advisable.